# Angular v15 *ngIf and [ngIf] differences

Tags: angular, upgrade

Currently, I'm trying to update Angular v14 to v15 including the new material components.

Some of my own components do not generate content anymore because of the strange behavior of the "*ngIf" directive.

```
hasSession:{{hasSession}}<br>
<div *ngIf="hasSession">A: *ngIf = {{hasSession}}</div>
<div [ngIf]="hasSession">B: [ngIf] = {{hasSession}}</div>
```

The "A:", based on "*ngIf" doesn't show. Output

> hasSession:true
> B: [ngIf] = true

Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

`*ngIf` is the [shorthand syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#shorthand-syntax) for angulars structural `ngIf` directive

```html
<div *ngIf="hasSession">A: *ngIf = {{hasSession}}</div>
```

Angular will expand this shorthand syntax to

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="hasSession">
 <div>A: *ngIf = {{hasSession}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

i.e. those 2 templates are the same, but the first is shorter and more readable.

I have no idea why your use of `[ngIf]` on a `div` worked/works at all:

```html
<div [ngIf]="hasSession">B: [ngIf] = {{hasSession}}</div>
```

i.e. this [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ejsjir?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) will show an error on the console, when you try to use this.

I also see no relation to Material Components, because `ngIf` is plain Angular.

Comment: `I have no idea why your use of [ngIf] on a div worked/works at all:` I think, because [ngIf] doesn't do anything, so the element is always valid, and thus displayed.

Comment: Actually it should result in a compile error like the Stackblitz example. Maybe you have some custom angular config, that deactivates some checks.

Comment: _"I also see no relation to Material Components, because ngIf is plain Angular."_ Because I migrated to Angular v15, and this command `ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration` removed a lot of _imports_ in my code. Making material components "Standalone" what that may be. 
The `ngIf` directive is part of the _CommonModule_ and imported, but maybe something else happened. That is my problem.

Comment: Then you should ask a new question, with tag `angular-material` and ideally include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When I add your working `<ng-template [ngIf]="hasSession" ...` solution in my App code. I got the same behavior as the `*ngIf` code. No option "C:" is displayed.
Thanks for your help, I will re-think my situation.

Comment: instead of adding something better remove the invalid stuff `<div [ngIf]="hasSession">B: [ngIf] = {{hasSession}}</div>`. and check for possible compile errors and warnings on the console.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some new insights, from the comments, I finally found my stupid error. The `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';` was missing.

It looks so simple and I didn't have these problems before. But after using the conversion tool of Angular Material components from v14 to v15. A lot of imports were gone. Including these most basic ones.

I didn't get any build errors, besides visual ones, like missing HTML component code.  This was the instruction I used, see [Run the migration tool](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#2-run-the-migration-tool).

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```